# Socket connection failed for unknown reasons

Tags: angularjs, node.js, socketcluster

I am trying to connect to remote socket server and i get an error: "Socket connection failed for unknown reasons"

spent a lot of time, and I could not find a solution (
Please, helpe me/ thanks

[image]

My client dep:
socketcluster-client 9.0.2,
angularjs 1.5.7[image]

Comment: You could try to add a on("disconnect") to log the reason

Comment: I i got "true" and that's all

Comment: its second error: Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'close' on 'WebSocket': The code must be either 1000, or between 3000 and 4999. 1 is neither

Answer (score 0):

You can try another system which has similar system, check ClusterWS

https://github.com/ClusterWS/ClusterWS

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same error and I was trying to connect to a third party external API that was providing data through websockets. If this is what you are trying to do, socketcluster may not work because it only enables connection with a socketcluster client and a socketcluster server regardless of whether they are in the same domain or different domain. Hope that helps